# Do I need to finish every level in the world to fight the boss?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I am playing Super Meat Boy, and failing terribly at it, but at least want to say I beat the bosses of each world. How many levels for each world do I need to complete to unlock the boss?

Comment: Please don't add thanks to the end of your posts.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that jeffrey. I am new here, so thought that would be more polite.

Comment: Its alright. Also, if you're going to put a game title, put it in the end, or don't put it at all. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to complete 17 levels in each world to unlock the boss. From the [Super Meat Boy Blog](http://supermeatboy.com/23/Whos_the_Boss___get_it____LOLZ_/#b):

> When you start a new chapter, all 20 main levels are unlocked. The
>   boss remains locked till you complete at least 17 of the 20 levels in
>   that chapter, and once you defeat the boss, the next chapter is
>   unlocked.

The exception to this rule is the 6th world (The End), which requires all 5 light world levels to be completed to unlock the boss. This world also has a dark world boss, which requires 85 of the dark world levels to be completed to unlock ([source](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_6:_The_End)).

Answer (score 1):

No, you only need to finish any arbitrary subset of a certain length of the levels for a stage, to be able to fight the boss.
I don't know how many levels you need to beat, but you can definitively beat a boss before you've finished all the levels of stage.